# No address showing on map click Android Google maps

Tags: android, google-maps

Ive added reverse Geocoding to my map and set the map to clickable. Everything works as it should except the address is not showing above the marker when i click the map.

my latLan is an array but thats the only way it would allow me to use the variable. i think the problem lies around this area but cant put my hand on it.

```
        @Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID); // changes view to hybrid
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true); // shows location on map

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER); // uses GPS only to get location

    double currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
    double currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();

    final LatLng[] latLng = {(new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude))};

    mMap.animateCamera(
            CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng[0], 18)); // This will zoom camera to updated lat and long without constant updates

    mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {// Setting a click event handler for the map


        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng arg0) {
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER); // uses GPS only to get location
            double currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
            double currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();

            //LatLng latLng;

            // Getting the Latitude and Longitude of the touched location
            latLng[0] = arg0;

            // Clears the previously touched position
            mMap.clear();

            // Animating to the touched position
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng[0]));

            // Creating a marker
            markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

            // Setting the position for the marker
            markerOptions.position(latLng[0]);

            // Placing a marker on the touched position
            mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

            // Adding Marker on the touched location with address
            new ReverseGeocodingTask(getBaseContext()).execute(latLng[0]);


        }
    });
    //new ReverseGeocodingTask(getBaseContext()).execute(latLng);
}

private class ReverseGeocodingTask extends AsyncTask<LatLng, Void, String> {
    Context mContext;

    public ReverseGeocodingTask(Context context) {
        super();
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(LatLng... params) {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(mContext);
        double latitude = params[0].latitude;
        double longitude = params[0].longitude;

        List<android.location.Address> addresses = null;
        String addressText = "";

        try {
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
            android.location.Address address = addresses.get(0);
            addressText = String.format("%s, %s, %s", address.getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0 ?
                    address.getAddressLine(0) : "", address.getLocality(), address.getCountryName());
        }
        return addressText;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String addressText) {

    markerOptions.title(addressText);
    mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Tested your code and found possible cause of error.

// Placing a marker on the touched position

```
mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
```

Upon implementing `addMarker()` before doing the ReverseGeocodingTask() and calling `addMarker()` again in the `onPostExecute()`. You can try adding an custom marker image large enough to make the address and the overwriting marker visible.

> **[Customize](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/marker#customize_the_marker_image) the marker image**
>
> You can replace the default marker image with a custom marker image, often called an icon. Custom icons are always set as a BitmapDescriptor, and defined using one of four methods in the BitmapDescriptorFactory class.

Code for custom image:

```
private static final LatLng MELBOURNE = new LatLng(-37.813, 144.962);
private Marker melbourne = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
.position(MELBOURNE)
.title("Melbourne")
.snippet("Population: 4,137,400")
.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.arrow)));
```

You can remove the first `mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);` before `new ReverseGeocodingTask(getBaseContext()).execute(latLng[0]);` then it your app will work as it should be.

Answer (score 0):

Use This Code May be work for getting Address

if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
            Address address = addresses.get(0);
            String addressLine = address.getAddressLine(0) + address.getAddressLine(1) + address.getAddressLine(2) + address.getAddressLine(3);
}